# Obtaining uniform randomness from non-uniform probabilities

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a coin that has a weird weight. The coin is weighted such that, when I flip it, one side is heavier than the other so I have a higher probability of getting H than I have of getting T. My probability of getting H is $p_1$ and my probability of getting T is $p_2$, with $p_1 + p_2 = 1$ and $p_1 \neq p_2$. What I want to do is create some method that guarantees a uniformly random outcome (where I flip my coin and my chances of writing down H or T are both $0.5$.)

Here is my idea. I flip the coin twice, which results in one out of four outcomes: If I get HT, I write down "H". If I get TH, I write down "T". If I get HH or TT, I start over and don't write anything down.

Will this ensure uniform randomness? My reasoning is that if I see HH or TT then the result occurred with a nonuniform probability (either $p_{1}^2$ or $p_{2}^2$) and I ignore it, but if I see HT or TH then the result occurred with probability $p_{1}p_{2}$ or $p_{2}p_{1}$, which are equal so I record it.

Comment: Yes, your idea works.  I think it is well explained.

Comment: Your reasoning is sound.

Comment: Just don't discard TT/HH yet if you get them. Keep them and if you get HH/TT on the next 2 throws produce a bit T/H. This way, you continue only if you get TTTT/HHHH hence speeding up the process a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   Your reasoning is sound.

Alternatively:

The probability of seeing `HT` given that you repeat the experiment until you see either `HT` or `TH` is:

$$\begin{align} & = p_1p_2 + (p_1^2+p_2^2)(p_1p_2+(p_1^2+p_2^2)(p_1p_2+ (p_1^2+p_2^2)(\ldots))) \\[1ex] & = p_1p_2 +(1-2p_1p_2 )(p_1p_2 +(1-2p_1p_2 )(p_1p_2 +(1-2p_1p_2 )(\ldots)))
\\[1ex] & = p_1p_2\big(1+(1-2p_1p_2)+(1-2p_1p_2 )^2+(1-2p_1p_2)^3+\cdots\big)
\\[1ex] & = \frac{p_1p_2 }{1-(1-2p_1p_2)} 
\\[1ex] & = \frac 1 2\end{align} $$